# BuildFireJS IFrame Allow Access To Camera and Mic

Tags: iframe, webrtc, buildfire

I am building an application with BuildFire.JS, and my app uses WebRTC. I look through how BuildFire works, and it embeds the Widget inside an iFrame when the app is being displayed in the plug-in interface. The IFrame looks as such:

```
<iframe id="widget" style="height: 100%; width: 100%; padding-top: 49px;" ng-style="{'padding-top': showNavigationBar ? '49px' : '0px' }" class="pluginFrame" seamless="" allowfullscreen="" sandbox="allow-scripts allow-forms  allow-same-origin allow-popups" ng-src="http://localhost:8080/widget/index.html?fid=widget&amp;appcontext=%xxxxxxxx"></iframe>
```

For my WebRTC components work, I need the iframe in the plugin interface to have the following options:

```
<iframe allow="camera; microphone" ></iframe>
```

Otherwise the camera will be blocked. How can I added to the IFrame in BuildJS to allow access to the camera and mic?

Answer (score 1):

SDK 1.65.2 has now support for required allow attributes (Android, iOS, Plugin Tester) and native permission requests for Android and iOS

Check the following new SDK functions:

https://sdk.buildfire.com/docs/camera/#isauthorized
https://sdk.buildfire.com/docs/camera/#requestauthorization

Comment: Quick note, I updated my Buildfire locally to 1.65.2 tested the plug-in and the features work. I then rebuilt my plug-in and uploaded to the site, and I still get permission denied. After inspecting the iframe, the camera/mic permissions are still not being allowed.

Comment: Here is a video of me replicating the issue: https://youtu.be/2wLE5YssthU

Comment: Changes were released to (Android, iOS, Plugin Tester). it is now released also to the emulator so you should be good now also on emulator  @DevinDixon.

Comment: @DevinDixon can you flag answers so others can benefit from them as you would ?

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure if this is hacky or not, but to fix the issue I found the iframe was being generated in the file `pluginTester/index.html`

So I added the following to the iframe in the file, linke 153:

```
<iframe  allow="camera; microphone" id="widget" ng-src="{{widgetSrc}}" style="height:100%; width:100%;"  ng-style="{'padding-top': showNavigationBar ? '49px' : '0px' }" class="pluginFrame" seamless allowfullscreen sandbox="allow-scripts allow-forms  allow-same-origin allow-popups"></iframe>
```

Feels hacky but it worked. This won't carry over to other clients who don't do the same modification, it would be nice if the allow functionality could be set in a configuration option.

If anyone has a better way, Im all ears.

Comment: That will only work within your tester, but will not work within an app.

Comment: @attila226 Can you explain the issue with it working in the App?

Comment: The file that you modified only exists within your local Plugin Tester. It is not part of your plugin and does not get deployed. Apps have their own internal files that you don't have access to, that contain the iframe.

Instead BuildFire requires that you update your plugin.json file to specify the required permissions/features. (See more info in the link below.) Having said that, I'm not sure if BuildFire currently supports using the camera and mic. 

https://sdk.buildfire.com/docs/features-list

Comment: Your solution is ok @d

Comment: @blue it fixes it in the testing area but attila226 was right in that it doesn't work when actually deploying the app.

Comment: @DevinDixon Buildfire team is testing it out and will probably add it soon

Comment: @blue because we specialize in WebRTC, is there anything we can do to assist the team in development?

Comment: @DevinDixon iOS seems to be good. However, for android NotReadableError is being received while using allow="camera; microphone". any pointers you can give ?

Comment: @blue can you give a gist of the error?

Comment: @DevinDixon it was an android native permission issue. We are looking how to require permission programmatically and we will continue testing afterwards.

Comment: @blue Just wanted to check back. Is there any time frame for a release? And do you need any support in testing? (as we are rolling it out to our clients on BuildFire, its mutually beneficial for us to test as well).

Comment: @DevinDixon it is looking good on our end. I expect it will be rolled out by next week

Comment: Thanks @blue. Is there anyway we can beta or alpha test before it rolls out?

Comment: @DevinDixon you can test it live now. note that you will need your app rebuilt to gain access to the new native permissions request.